Replicating /etc/profile.d under ~/.profile.d by copying the code from /etc/profile and changing the path
I'm trying to replicate the functionality of /etc/profile.d by copying the segment of /etc/profile that runs the scripts in profile.d in my ~/.profile, and have it run scripts under ~/.profile.d.
Here's my ~/.profile.
# ~/.profile: executed by the command interpreter for login shells.
# This file is not read by bash(1), if ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bash_login
# exists.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files for examples.
# the files are located in the bash-doc package.

# the default umask is set in /etc/profile; for setting the umask
# for ssh logins, install and configure the libpam-umask package.
#umask 022

# if running bash
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
    . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi

# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
fi

# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/.local/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"
fi

## Begin user section:
## Add $HOME/.profile.d
if [ -d "$HOME/.profile.d" ]; then
  for i in '$HOME/.profile.d/*.sh'; do
    if [ -r $i ]; then
      . $i
    fi
  done
  unset i
fi

Here's the golang.sh mentioned in that error:
GOPATH=$(go env GOPATH)
export PATH=$GOPATH/bin:$PATH
unset GOPATH

I also copied lines 33-35 from my ~/.profile into a separate script called test.sh and ran that as i="$HOME/.profile.d/golang.sh to confirm those lines do what I expect:
if [ -r $i ]; then
      echo "Can read ${i}" # Prior line is checking if the script file can be read, so if it does echo it here.
      . $i # this is what it originally did, sourcing the scripts inside a for loop.

fi

And, it does. I'm really confused. My understanding is the section I copied from /etc/profile iterates over every file in the given path (/etc/profile.d in the original, $HOME/.profile.d in my version), and checks if it can read them, then sources them (which is distinct from running them normally) if it can.
I have since run this script through ShellCheck as recommended by the bash tag, and it said to use single quotes in the for statement since double quotes break those. That fixed the error when logging into Cinnamon, but it still doesn't source the scripts in ~/.profile.d like I was expecting it to.
As you may have gathered, I'm a shell scripting noob.
I should note golang.sh has not been made executable. I don't think it needs to be, since it's being sourced and not executed, and /etc/profile.d scripts don't have +x set either. Also, doing . $HOME/.profile.d/golang.sh or source $HOME/.profile.d/golang.sh still sets my path like I expect.

I did use shellcheck, as directed by the bash tag. It is literally mentioned in the post. Why are you voting to close a post based on an assumption directly contradicted by the post?

Because when I copy/paste your code into http://shellcheck.net it reports several issues, including the one that's causing your problem and it tells you how to fix it. Saying you ran shellcheck but chose to post the code anyway isn't useful, posting shellcheck-clean code is as it avoids people wasting their time pointing out the issues that shellcheck can detect, e.g. see the answer you have so far.

To put it another way: The code you showed us contains obvious bugs. You say you have other code that "fixed the error when logging into Cinnamon, but it still doesn't source the scripts in ~/.profile.d like I was expecting it to". So, you have code that works on "Cinnamon" but not elsewhere but you haven't shown us that code so we can't help you debug that code. We can help you debug this code you showed us but shellcheck can do that, plus you say you've already done that anyway.

... The bash tag already told you to run shellcheck so us just commenting telling you to run shellcheck wouldn't be useful as you already know and apparently did that. So you've shown us code that isn't your at least partially fixed shellcheck-clean code, already know you should post shellcheck-clean code per the [tag:bash] tag but chose not to, and actually have problems with some other code you chose not to show us, and you're getting answers that shellcheck apparently already told you about and you fixed in that other code. So what should we do with this question other then close it?

Your for loop
for i in '$HOME/.profile.d/*.sh'; do
> echo "$i"
> done

produces
$HOME/.profile.d/*.sh

because you have single quotes, so it's not expanded.
Remove the single quotes. As mentioned by Toby Speight, you can double quote $HOME (e.g. "$HOME"/.profile.d/*.sh) to expand that part but not the rest of the expression.

Or better, double-quote the parameter expansion but not the wildcard: "$HOME"/.profile.d/*.sh

Thank you for taking this seriously and not fishing for a reason to close it. I'm trying what the two of you suggested now. One confusing part is double quoting the whole path is done elsewhere in the .profilein the section written by my distribution, not me. I can't tell why it works there but not in my own code.
I'll let you know if what I did works.

Thank you both, this works and has the expected behavior now, I can put scripts in my ~/.profile.d folder and they will run as expected. I will rewrite my question later so it makes more sense what I was trying to do and what I had already tried.
Thank you again.
